# Feminine version of "gentleman and a scholar"

Tags: phrases, expressions

Although I've often heard use of the phrase:

> You are a gentleman and a scholar

I have never heard a version appropriate for the fairer sex. I guess you could say a lady and a scholar?

Comment: There is no exact equivalent of the idiom, and "lady and a scholar" is just going to sound silly or patronizing. I suggest just dropping the idiom altogether and offering a gender neutral compliment such as "you are very generous and thoughtful". While you're at it, you could probably also 86 "fairer sex". Gender neutrality is hard, but worthwhile.

Comment: @MetaEd: Well, «fairer sex» already sounds silly and patroninizing, so that ship has already sailed! :)

Comment: The expression comes from a male-dominated world, as does the similar 'an officer and a gentleman'.

Comment: Both current answers take the phrase rather literally. I've always encountered it in a figurative sense, or simply as a means of expressing gratitude, and Wiktionary defines it simply a [an admirable person](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/a_gentleman_and_a_scholar).Perhaps you could expand on what you want your female equivalent to connote?

Comment: Reminds me of the old joke: _"You're a gentleman and a scholar... and I'm a liar."_

Comment: @Bryan Agee In legal parlance " My Lord " is no more in vogue. Equivalent expressions  " My Lady of of Justice" .. I never heard.

Comment: In an intellectual or academic setting, I would go with "a gentleperson and a scholar."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Perhaps a ["learned lady"](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22learned+lady%22&oq=%22learned+lady%22&gs_l=hp.12..0i30l3j0i5i30.3845.7963.1.9986.4.4.0.0.0.0.135.470.0j4.4.0...0.0.z4BccypwU6M&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=86fa095157477f71&biw=1366&bih=578) would be somewhat equivalent to "a gentleman and a scholar."

In this phrase, [*learned* (lur-nid) is defined as:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/learned)

> 1. having great knowledge or erudition
> 2. involving or characterized by scholarship

And [a lady is:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lady)

> 1. A well-mannered and considerate woman with high standards of proper behavior.

Comment: +1 I can totally parse, "You are a learned lady. Impressive." as the equivalent to, "My, you are a gentleman. And a scholar." Tone is up to imagination :).

Answer (score 11):

I don't think there is an exact equivalent.  The problem is that you are asking for a phrase with these incompatible connotations:

- It should be an old-fashioned idiom.  (A modern phrase would not have the same ring to it: notice that it's rare to call somebody a "scholar" these days, except in a rather narrow, technical sense.)
- It should suggest that she is scholarly.
- It should suggest that she possesses the qualities admired in a lady.

They are incompatible because, traditionally, female scholarship was **not** considered ladylike.  A female scholar was considered a kind of de-feminised monster.

Answer (score 9):

I can only think of one proper word for an intellectual woman: **bluestocking**. The etymology is given at [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bluestocking&allowed_in_frame=0) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluestocking), but as you would guess, originally the term was derisive and not appreciative. The situation is different today, for example, **Chambers** just states:

> An intellectual woman

There is another substitute from the French: **bas bleu**, but the etymological connotations are the same.

Comment: I always thought this meant just upper-class, but that's me just mixing it up with 'blue blooded'.

Answer (score 7):

This is a rather archaic phrase. The basic idea behind it is that the man in question, rather than being someone who defines himself by labor and/or physical activity (as typical men do), is someone who is genteel, and cares about higher intellectual pursuits. Its kind of the opposite of saying someone is "a man of action".

The problem with applying this to a woman is that unlike with men, this is exactly how a proper lady was *supposed* to be. Mostly. There weren't supposed to be any "women of action". So in theory there should be no need to say such a thing about a woman.

I'd say that if you are worried about gender equity, this phrase is so loaded down with gender biases that turning it around it hopeless. You should avoid it altogether.

Comment: I don’t think *archaic* means what you think it means.

Answer (score 2):

This is the most straightforward way to adapt it:

```
You are a gentlewoman and a scholar
```

Gentlewoman is simply the female version of gentleman; it's not significantly different in definition.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, the use of the old idiom was a conundrum for me as well.  So a number of years ago I created a better idiom that is equally praising for both genders.

To begin with, let's understand that the word 'gentleman" in the old idiom "You are a gentleman and a scholar" is not necessarily meant to be sexually biased for men. Instead, the old idiom is a compliment of the person's honorable character and to the person's wisdom.

Therefore, "gentleman" and "noble" equally describes the character of a person as being honorable.

So, if the person you are praising with my idiom "You are a noble and a scholar" truly reflects the character and the wisdom he or she has, then it will be perfectly understood and graciously appreciated.

~dbben

Comment: Although the question isn't entirely clear, I interpreted it as looking for an established idiom, not a neologism.

Comment: It rolls of the tongue and fills the bill - very nice.

Comment: This is great. The point of the original idiom is that it's silly and archaic, but also complimentary--this ticks all the boxes while sidestepping the (unnecessary) gendered language.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that *lady* is appropriate for the first term as a feminine equivalent.

It's certainly complimentary and could possibly put the other above yourself in the spirit of the original phrase.

The trouble is invariably with second word. Since this is essentially hyperbole, you must have a word that almost trumps the first.

For any man to be a *gentleman* AND a *scholar* he'd need to be truly diverse indeed.

And what lady doesn't want to be just as admired for her diverse talents.

And finally, it must also be old fashioned to truly fit the bill.

To me *angel* or *heroine* seems to fit the bill quite nicely.

> You're a lady and a heroine, my dear.
>
> You're a lady and an angel, my dear.

Comment: It's ANGEL, unless you're talking about trigonometry :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: that seems rather obtuse.

Answer (score 0):

I like the term "Admirable,"  and fortunately I just had the opportunity to express this with a person of the fairer sex (joking sarcasm intended),  I adjusted the phrase as follows,  "You are a kind and admirable person," and she,  22 years old, liked the compliment. And so, this is how I will respond be it male or female shall the opportunity arise.  Enjoyed reading all the responses.